# Height of an arbitrary tree

Tags: javascript, performance, tree

Given an arbitrary tree, where each node has a pointer to its first child (`node.left`) and to its closest sibling (`node.right`), how to find the height of the tree?

This is what I have:

```
function height(tree) {
  let h = 0;
  const queue = [[tree.root, 1]]; // pair (Node, depth)
  let n = 0; // use a pointer rather than shifting the array
  while (n < queue.length) {
    const [node, d] = queue[n];
    if (d > h) h = d; // if the current depth is greater then the max height so far, then update the max height
    // Traverse the siblings
    let r = node.right;
    while (r) {
      queue.push([r, d]); // siblings have the same depth
      r = r.right;
    }
    node.left && queue.push([node.left, d + 1]); // traverse the children
    n++; // go to the next Node
  }
  return h;
}
```

It's not recursive because the tree might be really big and I get overflow errors.
This code should work, but just wanted to know if there is a different/better way to do it.

Comment: Better way: never use single-letter variable names. Consider pushing an *object* rather than an *array* to the `queue` so that its representation is meaningful, eg `{ node, nodeHeight }`. Don't use `&&` if you aren't using the resulting truthy/falsey expression - better to use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
function height(node){
   if(!node) return 0;
   var leftHeight = height(node.left);
   var rightHeight = height(node.right);

   return Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
}
```

The best approach is to use a recursion. It is clean and readable.

Comment: Yes, but I get a stack overflow for very large trees.